# Using aggregate to sum values greater than 70 in R

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I am trying to sum values that are greater than 70 in several different data sets. I believe that aggregate can do this but my research has not pointed to an obvious solution to obtaining the values that exceed seventy in my data sets. I have first used aggregate to get the daily max values and put these values into the data frame called yearmaxs. Here is my code and what I have tried:

## number of times O3 >70 in a year per site

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")
library(openair)
library(lubridate)
filedir <- "C:/Users/dfmcg/Documents/Thesisfiles/8hravg"
myfiles <- c(list.files(path = filedir))
paste(filedir, myfiles, sep = '/')
npsfiles <- c(paste(filedir, myfiles,sep = '/'))

for (i in npsfiles[22]) {
  
  x <- substr(i,45,61)
  y <- paste('C:/Users/dfmcg/Documents/Thesisfiles/exceedenceall', x, sep='/')
  timeozone <- import(i, date="DATES", date.format = "%Y-%m-%d %H", header=TRUE, na.strings="NA")

  overseventy <- c()
  yearmaxs <- aggregate(rolling.O3new ~ format(as.Date(date)), timeozone, max)
  colnames(yearmaxs) <- c("date", "daymax")
  overseventy <- aggregate(daymax ~ format(as.Date(date)), yearmaxs, FUN = length,
        subset = as.numeric(daymax) > 70)
  colnames(overseventy) <- c("date", "daymax")
  aggregate(daymax ~ format(as.Date(date), "%Y"), overseventy, sum)
```

I have also tried: sum > "70 and sum(daymax > "70).

My other idea at this point is using a for loop to iterate through the values. I was hoping that a could use aggregate again to sum the values of interest. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, yearmas is my daily max in the entire time series while timeozone is the entire data set. However, I have solved my issue and am exporting it now! But, I have updated the question to include a final solution. However, I do wish that  did not have to do aggregate three times to get this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
aggregate(daymax ~ format(as.Date(date)), yearmaxs, FUN = length,
          subset = as.numeric(daymax) > 70)
```

To things:

1. you need numerical comparison, so use `as.numeric(daymax) > 70` not `daymax > "70"`;
2. use the `subset` argument in `aggregate.formula`.

Comment: Yes, I want the number of years not the values in the year. I just realized this myself. Would length give the number of values exceeding 70 in a year?

Comment: I have updated the question to show what I am getting now.